# iPhone web app launched from home screen - links only work after scrolling off the top of the page?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, mobile, web, jqtouch

I'm creating a mobile web app that is intended to be deployed to the user's home screen. The app works perfectly fine within Mobile Safari and other mobile browsers, but when deployed to the home screen none of the links (they're animated with jQTouch, if that makes any difference) will work until I scroll the first page upwards until it's partially off the screen - everything's fine after that. Is this an issue with my DOM?